# GWT: Failed to load module

Tags: gwt

I wanted to organize my folders my own way but it's not working so far.

This is my directory structure

src

- com.tutorial.client

  - DictionaryModule
- com.tutorial.module

  - Tutorial.gwt.xml

Tutorial.gwt.xml:

```
<module rename-to="tutorial">
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
  <entry-point class="com.tutorial.client.DictionaryModule"/>
</module>
```

DictionaryModule

```
package com.tutorial.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class DictionaryModule implements EntryPoint {
    HorizontalPanel dictionaryPanel;
    Label wordLabel;

    public DictionaryModule(){
        dictionaryPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
        wordLabel = new Label("Word");
    }
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        dictionaryPanel.add(wordLabel);
        RootPanel.get("dictionary").add(dictionaryPanel);
    }   
}
```

but I get this error:

> **[ERROR]** Unable to find type
>   'com.tutorial.client.DictionaryModule'
>   **[ERROR]** Hint: Previous compiler errors
>   may have made this type unavailable
>   **[ERROR]** Hint: Check the inheritance
>   chain from your module; it may not be
>   inheriting a required module or a
>   module may not be adding its source
>   path entries properly [ERROR] Failure
>   to load module 'tutorial'

Answer (score 4):

I know you must have manage to solve this ages ago but for others, here is how I solved this:

I have a gwt project using Hibernate framework and uses Maven2 for build management.

Goto: Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export . Now make sure that GWT SDK is *above* Maven and JRE/JDK libraries.

The reason is since there are multiple class files with the same name in multiple libraries, the compiler has no way to decide which one to give priority to, so we must control this by specifying the Ordering.

Comment: this is the only thing which worked for me among all the answers

Answer (score 1):

Place gwt.xml in the directory containing *client* directory and also add the following to it:

```
   <source path="module" />
   <source path="client" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your directory structure.

```
 - com.tutorial.module.client

       DictionaryModule

 - com.tutorial.module

        Tutorial.gwt.xml
```

Then add the following in  `Tutorial.gwt.xml`

```
<module rename-to="tutorial">
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
  <entry-point class="com.tutorial.module.client.DictionaryModule"/>
    <source path='client'/>
</module>
```