# GWT Compilation error with GWT 2.5

Tags: gwt

I am trying to compile a GWT project but I am getting the following error: Can anyone please explain if I am missing anything? I have downloaded the GWT plugins for the eclipse.

```
Compiling module com.nolij.nolijweb.ui.entrypoint.user.UserInterface   Validating units:
      Ignored 28 units with compilation errors in first pass. Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.    Finding entry point classes
      [ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/gwt/core/client/GWTBridge.java'
         [ERROR] Line 25: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWTBridge; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.nolij.nolijweb.ui.entrypoint.user.client.UserInterface'
         [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
         [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
```

Comment: please post your `module.gwt.xml`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651138/gwt-failed-to-load-module?rq=1